# Problema con cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

He instalado cocoapods, pero al instalar los pods en mi proyecto me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Albertos-Mac:Proyecto1 alberto$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Esto me aparece despues de unos 15 minutos o mas que se queda asi:

```
Albertos-Mac:Proyecto1 alberto$ pod install
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

EDITADO

Al desinstalar todo y volverlo a instalar me aparece este error:

```
Albertos-Mac:Users alberto$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Fetching: cocoapods-downloader-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.1.0
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
Albertos-Mac:Users alberto$
```

Y si despues pruebo a hacer un pod setup me aparece esto:

```
Albertos-Mac:Users alberto$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Fetching: cocoapods-downloader-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.1.0
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
Albertos-Mac:Users alberto$
```

Alguna solucion??
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo desinstala `CocoaPods`:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

Y después vuelve a instalarlo con:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Casi seguro que el problema es no utilizar `sudo`.

Una vez finalizado, ya podrás hacer `pod install` o `pod update` de forma normal.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Si aparece el error después de desinstalar `Cocoapods`, hay que reinstalarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: He realizsdo los pasos que me has indicado pero me aparece un error, lo he añadido en mi pregunta el error. @mhergon

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente. Gracias @mhergon